# What is Gapps (Google Apps)?

Tags: applications

I have some questions regarding Gapps:

- What is Gapps? Is it a custom ROM?
- Do I have to install it on my Android 4.4 device?

Answer (score 3):

GAPPS is not a custom ROM. It means "Google Applications" and usually includes Play Store, Gmail, Google Calender, and more. If you have some of these applications, then you already have some GAPPS.

Most users will only need to install GAPPS if they have installed a custom ROM that did not have GAPPS included.

Comment: Can u tell me how to install it?

Comment: You can install GAPPS by flashing a GAPPS zip file using either ClockworkMod (CWM) or Team Win’s Recovery Project (TWRP). Please see this page for details: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps#Installation

Comment: GAPPS is not required for normal smart phone functionality. Calls, SMS messages, internet and Bluetooth will work without.

Answer (score 3):

"GApps" is an unofficial package distributed in several forms and places containing Google applications and frameworks, **not a ROM**. You don't *have to* install GAPPS, but many users may wish to do so in order to access Google Play store and some applications that depend on Google Play services. Smart phone functions such as calling, SMS messages, internet, Wi-Fi and Bluetooth work without GApps.

There's a replacement project [MicroG](https://microg.org/) in development and [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/) is a comprehensive repository and "app store" for open source Android applications.